# Place text in column B when it gets colored (VBA/Excel)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've been working on the code below. The code will color every row where the value "test" is found. When "test" is found, I want the program to also put "test" in column B.

I already tried something, as you can see below with "Value", but I can't figure out how I can assign column B to it.

```
Sub colorF()
  For i = 1 To 3000
    For Kolom = 1 To 25
    ColInd = ""

    If InStr(1, Cells(i, Kolom), "test") > 0 Then ColInd = 3: Value = "test"

    Rows(i).Select
    If Not ColInd = "" Then Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = ColInd
    Next Kolom
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm a bit puzzled by what you want to happen in column B. Do you mean that if, say, the program finds "test" in cell X25, you want your procedure to put the value "test" in cell B25 (as well as coloring in row 25)? If you could explain that a bit more in your question, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You should link the Value to the cell:

```
range("B" & i).Value = "test"
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I did tried range, but not in combination with &i.

Comment: good to hear it worked out for you, please mark the answer as the answer so others will know you are helped already.

Comment: also please tell your class mates about it, so they dont flood this forum with similar questions. Thank you